# Chrome is having problems loading a localhost page

Tags: google-chrome, localhost

While developing, I put the row "127.0.0.4  bla.localhost" on /etc/hosts and then I access through the browser like http://bla.localhost.

Sometimes chrome just doesn't open the address at all. Then I try with firefox, opera, wget, telnet on port 80 and all of them works except for Chrome.

This is driving me crazy because I don't even know from where to start on this problem.

I'm using Fedora 17 with Chrome 25.0.1364.97 . I run chrome with the following parameters google-chrome --enable-file-cookies --purge-memory-button --enable-internal-flash --enable-logging --v=10

Does anybody knows how to solve that problem or could at least give me a hint about where to start looking?

P.S.:

I see the following errors on my console

```
[13811:13837:0227/171354:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(624)] Failed to get name owner. Got     org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.chromium.Mtpd': no such name
[13811:13837:0227/171354:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(624)] Failed to get name owner. Got org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.chromium.Mtpd': no such name
[13811:13811:0227/171355:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(529)] Failed to call method: org.chromium.Mtpd.EnumerateStorages: object_path= /org/chromium/Mtpd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.chromium.Mtpd was not provided by any .service files
[13811:13811:0227/171355:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
[13811:13811:0227/171420:ERROR:omnibox_view_gtk.cc(431)] Not implemented reached in virtual void OmniboxViewGtk::ApplyCaretVisibility()
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @Barmar, I just updated the question with the errors.

Comment: Those are from the Chrome Developer Tools console?

Comment: No, it's the output from the terminal.

Comment: If you want to know why Chrome is having a problem, look in its own console.

Comment: nothing happens on the developer tools console because it doesn't load the page. It is stucked at "Waiting for bla.localhost...". On the "network" tab, I can see the request pending.

Comment: I changed my chrome version to 27.0.1423.0 dev (the unstable version). And the same still happening. I can't determine what is triggering this issue. Also It happend with google.com. Google doesn't load just on chrome, nothing happens on dev console.

Comment: Go into the Network tab of Developer Tools to see if it's even trying to connect.

Comment: Yes, it's stucked on pending.

Comment: That suggests the issue is in the server, although that doesn't explain why other browsers work. Does the server access log show that the request was received?

Comment: It might be related to this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=179760 (just guessing based on the latter errors you had).